# calculate encounter history for mark-recapture models

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to create (in R) an encounter history for use within [RMark](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMark/); i.e. if an encounter has occurred return a "1" and if the encounter did not occur return a "0".

Sample data:

```
zm <- structure(list(date.time = structure(c(1365905306, 1365919237, 
1365923863, 1365929487, 1365931725, 1365942003, 1365945361, 1366143204, 
1366159355, 1366159863, 1366164285, 1366202496, 1366224357, 1366238428, 
1366243685, 1366250254, 1366252570, 1366314236, 1366315282, 1366386242
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), station = c("M1", 
"M2", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M3", "M4", "M7", "L1", "M1", "M2", "M2", 
"L4", "M2", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M1", "M2", "M1"), code = c(10908, 
10908, 10897, 10908, 10908, 10897, 10897, 10908, 10908, 10914, 
10914, 10916, 10908, 10917, 10910, 10917, 10917, 10913, 10913, 
10896)), .Names = c("date.time", "station", "code"), row.names = c(5349L, 
51L, 60L, 7168L, 65L, 7178L, 70L, 6968L, 8647L, 5362L, 79L, 94L, 
9027L, 96L, 105L, 7200L, 114L, 5382L, 123L, 5388L), class = "data.frame")
```

Possible encounter history (stations to check if encounter occurred or not):

```
rec<- c("M1", "M2","M3","M4","M5","M6","M7")
```

What is important is that the encounter history output refers to the order of `rec` above.

So for each `code` I want to see if it was detected at the first station i.e. `"M1"` and if so then return a '1', then see if it was detected at the second station `"M2"` and if not return a "0"; this will ultimately end up as a character string of 0's and 1's.

I am able to get data which is in `rec` through:

```
library("plyr")
zm2 <- ddply(zm, c("code"), function(df)
 data.frame(arrive=(df[which(df$station %in% rec),])))
```

However I am unsure how to run this in order of `rec` and then to return either a '0' or '1'.

Ultimately I want a data.frame output structure follows:

```
ch       code
00101    1
00011    2
```

and so on...

Comment: Maybe `table` helps? `table(zm$code, zm$station)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table()` is indeed the way to go, follow by `paste0()` to collapse the table into a string.  (Thanks for the reproducible example!)

```
rec <- sort(unique(zm$station))
cfun <- function(x) {
    tab <- with(x,table(factor(station,levels=rec)))
    data.frame(ch=paste0(as.numeric(tab),collapse=""))
}
library(plyr)
ddply(zm,"code",cfun)
##    code      ch
## 1 10896 0010000
## 2 10897 0001110
## 3 10908 1111111
## 4 10910 0001000
## 5 10913 0011000
## 6 10914 0011000
## 7 10916 0001000
## 8 10917 0001110
```

Or as suggested by @alexis_laz:

```
tab2 <- with(zm,table(code,station))
ctab <- apply(tab2,1,paste0,collapse="")
data.frame(code=names(ctab),ch=ctab)
```

(the code is listed twice, once as a row name and once as a column).
The latter version is probably a bit faster, in case you have a really large data set or need to do this thousands of times ...

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd provide an alternate solution to creating the encounter history, in case you ever want to cross-check results with different methods:

```
## Begin
zm$code <- as.character(zm$code)
tag.list = as.character(unique(zm$code)) # create a vector of all tags (codes) detected
sta.list = as.character(unique(zm$station)) # make a vector of the station names

# create empty data frame for filling encounter history later
enc.hist = as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,(length(tag.list)*length(sta.list))),
                            length(tag.list), length(sta.list)))
colnames(enc.hist) = sta.list
rownames(enc.hist) = tag.list

# fill in data frame using a for-loop:
for (i in 1:length(sta.list))
{
  sub <- zm[zm$station == sta.list[i],] #subset datos down to just the station you're currently looping
  subtags <- unique(sub$code) #creates vector of tags present at that station
  enc.hist[,i] <- tag.list %in% subtags #fills in the column of enc.hist with True or False if that tag is seen or not
}
head(enc.hist) # you now have a matrix with TRUE (1)/FALSE (0) for encounters:

 M1   M2    M3    M4    M7    L1    L4
10908  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
10897 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
10914  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
10916 FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
10917 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
10910 FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

## Finally, use logical syntax to convert TRUE to '1' and FALSE to '0'
enc.hist[enc.hist==TRUE] <- 1
enc.hist[enc.hist==FALSE] <- 0
enc.hist

      M1 M2 M3 M4 M7 L1 L4
10908  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
10897  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
10914  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
10916  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
10917  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
10910  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
10913  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
10896  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Now you can use @alexis_laz's excellent code on `enc.hist` for collapsing into an .inp for RMARK.

Much more verbose, but provides an alternate method that (hopefully) works as well and preserves the station order, although the for-loop would certainly slow you down if you have millions of detections.